# Making "if" statements into "switch"

Tags: java

In java, I need to use 3 case statements. It will ask for user input and if they enter a number less than or equal to 0, it tells them something. If they enter a 10 or greater, it says something else. If they enter between 1 and 9 it says something and adds a word for every number greater than 1 up to what they entered. So far I have figured out how to do most of that by using "if" statements but it needs to be done using "switch". Also, I havent really looked into adding the extra words on the end of the sentence if its between 1-9 so it would be cool if you could point me in the right direction for that too.

Here is part of my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

String Str = "Add more to number";
String Str2 = "Too much number";
String Str3 = "Just right";
int num1 = 0;
Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("How much number");
num1 = scanIn.nextInt();

if (num1 <= 0) System.out.println(Str);
else if (num1 > 10) System.out.println(Str2);
else if (num1 < 10 || num1 > 1) System.out.println(Str3);
```

Comment: `switch` would not fit into this problem naturally. It's about strict equality comparisons specifically.

Comment: Do you understand the logic of switch-case blocks (i.e., how they work)?  If so, what implementation have you tried and, if it didn't work as you expected, have you attempted to step through your code with a debugger to see where your expected results deviate from what actually happens during execution?

Comment: You might be able to abuse compareTo to make a switch statement, but why?

Comment: I am new to java so I don't know much about how switch works. From what I've seen online, switch would not work for this kind of thing but someone from my class told me that's what we needed to use.

Comment: Whoever said that should not be giving Java coding advice.

Comment: So am I on right track so far with my code that I have now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct with using if statements. Like everyone has stated case/switch would not be a natural fit for this. Also it looks like you are doing a number guessing game so you will want to ask for input repeatedly until the user guesses correctly and you will want them to guess a specific number. In my example I use 7 as my number to guess.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Str = "Add more to number";
    String Str2 = "Too much number";
    String Str3 = "Just right";
    int num1 = 0;
    int numToGuess = 7; //you can change this to whatever you want
    Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    //we want to ask for a number until it is the same as our numToGuess
    do {
        System.out.println("How much number");
        num1 = scanIn.nextInt();
        //if the number entered is less let them know
        if(num1 < numToGuess)
        {
            System.out.println(Str);
        }
        else if(num1 > numToGuess)
        {
            System.out.println(Str2);
        }
    } while (num1 != numToGuess); 
    //we will continue to ask until our num1 is equal to numToGuess

    //since we got out we guessed correctly
    System.out.println(Str3);

}//main method
```